# Mingw console application opens a separate console window even when starting from Windows Console

Tags: c, mingw-w64

Recently, I tried to compile a simple console hello world application for the Windows operating system with Mingw from Linux:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("i = %d\n", i);
      sleep(1);
   }
}
```

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc hello.c -o hello.exe -mconsole
```

To my surprise, when I run it from Windows Console (cmd.exe) it creates a separate console window rather than printing my stdout messages to the same console window. What's even worse, I couldn't find my problem's description anywhere, even here on SO. For comparison, I tried running a 3rd-party console program from Windows Console (usbip.exe), but just as I expected, it worked like a charm.

Is such behavior a kind of bug in my Mingw-W64 C standard library version or somewhat expected? Is there any way to get rid from this annoying behavior?

upd. Some people suggested omitting `-mconsole` during the compilation process. Unfortunately, it works in exactly the same way. I've even tried `-mwindows` and this way it doesn't opens a new console window, but doesn't prints anything to my console window either (and actually returns the control to cmd.exe immediately just as expected when running executables belonging to `-mwindows` subsystem).

Comment: what if you omit the `-mconsole` flag?

Comment: Best guess: the `-mconsole` option tells your compiler that the executable should always open a new console in which to run.  This serves the case where you run it by, say, clicking its icon on the start menu.  If you want to run it from an existing console only, with input and ouptut connected to that console, then it would be worth testing wheth omitting `-mconsole` gets you there.

Comment: It works in exactly the same way even when I omit ``-mconsole``. I've even tried -mwindows and this way it doesn't opens a new console window, but doesn't prints anything to my console window either.

Comment: Well, `-mwindows` is definitely not the way to go.  Here are the docs for GCC's Windows-specific options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html.  It looks like `-mconsole` is appropriate for your case, and I think it is the MinGW default, too.  I don't have an explanation for the behavior you describe, and I've never seen it myself nor heard about it before.

Answer (score 2):

After messing up for a while, it turned out to be a Windows Defender-related issue. I compiled another console hello world program with another filename not known to Windows yet, and this time it worked as expected.

upd2. Finally, this turns out to be related to something known as the "Installer Detection Technology of UAC". The way to avoid this behavior is to specify a corresponding `requestedExecutionLevel` in the manifest: https://superuser.com/questions/1677002/mechanism-of-windows-uac-shield-buckler-appendage-on-exe-files

Comment: _"it turned out to be a Windows Defender-related issue"_ -- more detail would be helpful for anyone else who comes across this Q&A with a similar problem. How did you determine that this was related to Windows Defender (aside from that every weird problem on Windows seems related to Windows Defender)? What does this have to do with the name of the compiled file? That last bit seems very strange. I'm skeptical that the file name is the real issue.

Comment: Here are the steps to reproduce that problem that are working for me on Win 7:

1) Create two helloworld binaries and name them as hello.exe and helloupdate.exe
2) Upload both to Virtualbox shared folder (/net/win7 / Z:\). Mention that hello.exe doesn't has a shield icon, while helloupdate.exe does.
3) Try to run both from console. Notice that hello.exe runs without any problems, while helloupdate.exe doesn't starts
4) Copy both to C:\ and try to run from Windows Console. Now you see that hello.exe is working as expected, while helloupdate.exe opens a new console window when being run.

Comment: Speaking honestly I also was a bit skeptical about that. Maybe I'm wrong that this has something to do with Windows Defender (I'm not a so big expert in Windows), but as you see, this definitely has something to do with filenames and security.

Comment: After searching more, this turned out to be caused by installer autodetection feature. It appears that I have to add some ``requestedExecutionLevel`` in the manifest in order to avoid that. https://superuser.com/questions/1677002/mechanism-of-windows-uac-shield-buckler-appendage-on-exe-files

Comment: That shield icon means that `helloupdate.exe` requires administrator privileges to execute; this is probably why a new console window (one with administrator privileges) is opened. I'm not sure why your first file does not require elevated privileges, but the second does (or where in the process that this occurs). I find the Windows privileges model generally to be a big pain in the butt, though.

Comment: You're absolutely right. As for the reason why the second file requires elevates privileges - that's because it's filename contains a keyword that triggers somewhat known as the "Installer Detection Technology of UAC".

Comment: I guess it isn't the file name alone; uploading the file to a Virtualbox folder must bring the extra scrutiny. You have added a lot of details in the comments here that really belong in your original question; without them there is no way to begin to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now. Just the fact that all of that (especially the filenames) can have something to do with my problem was a big surprise for me too.